# I/O Relative Paths

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with relative paths in my program. The absolute path to the file which I want to use is:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\Project1\src\files\test.txt
```

Now, I'm unsure of how to make this a relative path, I've tried:

```
.\files\test.txt
```

Which throws an error at me, I don't know how to make this go up a folder and read from the test.txt file.

Comment: What error does it throw ?

Comment: How are you using the path? With `File`, with the class loader, etc.?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify but like so:

                fileIn = new Scanner(new File("The Path I gave"));

The error that it throws is:

    java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\cells\Glider.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

(My catch block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.\files\test.txt` is correct, if and only if you run your program from the `src` directory, and use file IO to read the file, and not resource loading using the class loader.